# Prevent Label to be re-aligned after askdirectory() is closed

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I built a window which display some labels, an entry field and a button. The button opens a `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()`. After I choose a directory and close the dialog another label is updated along with the text entry with the choice.

The problem is that after this happens the description of the text entry (another Label on its left) is realigned in its cell. I don't know why this happens, is there any behind-the-scenes behaviour which I'm not aware of?

Here's the sample code I use.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk


def folderDiag():
    scanfolder.set(filedialog.askdirectory())

c = (N, W, S, E)
scanfolder = StringVar()

root = Tk()
root.title("Testing")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=c)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ttk.Label(frame, text="Welcome!",
          font="TkDefaultFont 24 bold").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4,
                                             sticky=c)
# This label will be centered after dialog is closed
ttk.Label(frame, text="Select folder to scan:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=scanfolder).grid(column=2, row=2)

scan_folder_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=scanfolder).grid(column=3,
                                                                   row=1)
browse_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse...",
                           command=folderDiag).grid(column=4, row=1)

root.mainloop()
exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you need this:

```
|    0    |         1         |      2     |  # Column number
|                Welcome!                  |
| Select  |       Entry       |   Button   |
| Your label                               |
```

So:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

def folderDiag():
    scanfolder.set(filedialog.askdirectory())

root = Tk()

c = (N, W, S, E)
scanfolder = StringVar()

root.title("Testing")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=c)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=0)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ttk.Label(frame, text="Welcome!",
          font="TkDefaultFont 24 bold").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3,
                                             sticky=c)
ttk.Label(frame, text="Select folder to scan:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=scanfolder, justify=LEFT).grid(column=0, columnspan=3, row=2, sticky=W)

scan_folder_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=scanfolder)
scan_folder_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=EW)
browse_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse...",
                           command=folderDiag)
browse_button.grid(column=2, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Your code create this layout:

```
|   0    | 1 |    2    |    3   |    4   |
| Welcome                       |  ---   |
| Select | - |   ---   | Entry  | Button |
|   ---  | - |  Label  |   ---  |   ---  |
```

[image]

For some reason you leave #1 empty. Its width = const = 0. Forget about it.
`Select` doesn't attached to `Entry`. Columns #1 and #2 separate them. `Select` attached to right edge of #0 column.
When you update `Label` you increase width of #2 column => you increase space between #0 (`Select`) and #3 (`Entry`). `Select` stay attached to right edge of #0.

Comment: This is a useful workaround, but it is not what I asked. I commented the label that will realign on closing the dialog and I want to know _why_ it realigns.